# How to select most recent timestamp per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a report running every hour, showing disk space usage of a database.
this is then sent via email.

I would like to change it to show the stats as at the last snapshot_date

data as below

```
Day Date    Time    WeekNo  Data_Size_MB    Used_Data_MB

Friday  10-Mar-17   11:00   11  118784  92670.33

Friday  10-Mar-17   10:00   11  118784  92653.96

Friday  10-Mar-17   09:00   11  118784  92641.16

Friday  10-Mar-17   08:00   11  118784  92636.39

Friday  10-Mar-17   07:00   11  118784  92584.42

Thursday    09-Mar-17   23:00   11  118784  92586.25

Thursday    09-Mar-17   22:00   11  118784  92586.06

Thursday    09-Mar-17   21:00   11  118784  92585.85
```

the sql below

```
select  Day = datename(dw,snapshot_Date),
        Date = convert(varchar(19), Snapshot_Date, 106),
        Time = substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, snapshot_Date, 108),0,6),
        WeekNo = DATEPART(week, snapshot_Date),
        Data_Size_MB = Data_Size_MB,
        Used_Data_MB = Used_Data_MB,
        Data_Full_Pcnt = Data_Full_Pcnt,
        Log_Size_MB = Log_Size_MB,
        Free_Log_MB = Free_Log_MB,
        Log_Full_Pcnt = Log_Full_Pcnt,  
        snapshot_Date            
from Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
where database_name='IDEAL'
order by snapshot_date desc
```

but I would like it to return

```
Day Date    Time    WeekNo  Data_Size_MB    Used_Data_MB

Friday  10-Mar-17   11:00   11  118784  92670.33

Thursday    09-Mar-17   23:00   11  118784  92586.25
```

ie the last snapshot for each day

nb: I have chopped of some of the columns returned in the data

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create an intermediate table where you add a rownumber per date. Then you can select only the first row per date.

```
select *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rownum 
into #some_temp
from Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
where database_name='IDEAL'

select  Day = datename(dw,snapshot_Date),
    Date = convert(varchar(19), Snapshot_Date, 106),
    Time = substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, snapshot_Date, 108),0,6),
    WeekNo = DATEPART(week, snapshot_Date),
    Data_Size_MB = Data_Size_MB,
    Used_Data_MB = Used_Data_MB,
    Data_Full_Pcnt = Data_Full_Pcnt,
    Log_Size_MB = Log_Size_MB,
    Free_Log_MB = Free_Log_MB,
    Log_Full_Pcnt = Log_Full_Pcnt,  
    snapshot_Date            
from #some_temp
where database_name='IDEAL' and rownum = 1
```

Of course you can also do a nested `from (select ...) b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTES like this

```
with mondayTable as(
select  Day = datename(dw,snapshot_Date),
        Date = convert(varchar(19), Snapshot_Date, 106),
        Time = substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, snapshot_Date, 108),0,6),
        WeekNo = DATEPART(week, snapshot_Date),
        Data_Size_MB = Data_Size_MB,
        Used_Data_MB = Used_Data_MB,
        Data_Full_Pcnt = Data_Full_Pcnt,
        Log_Size_MB = Log_Size_MB,
        Free_Log_MB = Free_Log_MB,
        Log_Full_Pcnt = Log_Full_Pcnt,  
        snapshot_Date            
from Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
where database_name='IDEAL' and datename(dw,snapshot_Date) = 'Monday'
order by snapshot_date desc
)

tuesdayTable as(
select  Day = datename(dw,snapshot_Date),
        Date = convert(varchar(19), Snapshot_Date, 106),
        Time = substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR, snapshot_Date, 108),0,6),
        WeekNo = DATEPART(week, snapshot_Date),
        Data_Size_MB = Data_Size_MB,
        Used_Data_MB = Used_Data_MB,
        Data_Full_Pcnt = Data_Full_Pcnt,
        Log_Size_MB = Log_Size_MB,
        Free_Log_MB = Free_Log_MB,
        Log_Full_Pcnt = Log_Full_Pcnt,  
        snapshot_Date            
from Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
where database_name='IDEAL' and datename(dw,snapshot_Date) = 'Tuesday'
order by snapshot_date desc
)
SELECT  *
FROM    mondayTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    tuesdayTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `row_number()`:

```
select sds.*
from (select sds.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by time desc) as seqnum
      from Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
      where database_name = 'IDEAL'
     ) sds
where seqnum = 1
order by snapshot_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

We can omit using of ROW_NUMBER() function and numbering of each row.

In the following query, I'm looking for the maximum `Snapshot_Date` for each day with grouping by date (`CAST(Snapshot_Date AS DATE)`) in CTE (`LatestDailySnapshot`) and then join the results to original table to extract records for these dates.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(50) = 'IDEAL';

WITH LatestDailySnapshot AS
(
    SELECT MAX(Snapshot_Date) AS Latest_Snapshot_Date
    FROM Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
    WHERE Database_Name = @DatabaseName
    GROUP BY CAST(Snapshot_Date AS Date)
)
SELECT *
FROM Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
WHERE Database_Name = @DatabaseName
JOIN LatestDailySnapshot ON Latest_Snapshot_Date = Snapshot_Date
ORDER BY snapshot_date
```

**Note 1**: It would be more effective if you have an index on (`Database_Name, Snapshot_Date`).

**Note 2**: This approach wouldn't work correctly if you have more than one row per (`Database_Name`, `Snapshot_Date`) combination. It means that the following query should not return any result:

```
SELECT Database_Name, Snapshot_Date, COUNT(*) AS RowsPerCombination
FROM Ideal_Risk.dbo.Sybase_Disk_Space
GROUP BY Database_Name, Snapshot_Date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```